# Javascript tabs, Adding active class to element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add active class to the one element and remove that class from all other 'article' elements, hide them. Just normal javascript tabs.

I'm new in JS and can't resolve this problem.

Here is my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a8bvp0fn/

SOLVED: https://jsfiddle.net/y8sa3e0c/

thx

```
<style>
.article-1, .article-2, .article-3 {
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
display: none;
}

.article-1 {
background: red;
}

.article-2 {
background: green;
}

.article-3 {
background: blue;
}

.active {
display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<h2 class="output" data-tab="1">BUTTON 1</h2>
<h2 class="output" data-tab="2">BUTTON 2</h2>
<h2 class="output" data-tab="3">BUTTON 3</h2>

<div class="article-1"></div>
<div class="article-2"></div>
<div class="article-3"></div>


<script>
var output = document.querySelectorAll('.output');

output.forEach(function(item) {

item.onclick = function(){

var datas = this.dataset.tab;
var elem = document.querySelector('.article-' + datas);

elem.classList.toggle('active');

}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var output = document.querySelectorAll('.output');

output.forEach(function(item) {

  item.onclick = function() {
    var datas = this.dataset.tab;
    var elem = document.querySelector('.article-' + datas);
    let AllElems = document.querySelector('.active');
    if (AllElems) {
      AllElems.classList.remove('active');
    }
    elem.classList.add("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.article-1,
.article-2,
.article-3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
}

.article-1 {
  background: red;
}

.article-2 {
  background: green;
}

.article-3 {
  background: blue;
}

.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="output" data-tab="1">BUTTON 1</h2>

<h2 class="output" data-tab="2">BUTTON 2</h2>

<h2 class="output" data-tab="3">BUTTON 3</h2>



<div class="article-1"></div>
<div class="article-2"></div>
<div class="article-3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to get all the article elements with:

```
var articles = document.getElementsByClassName('article');
```

And then in the `onclick` method, remove the active class from all articles other than the one you clicked:

```
for (let i = 0; i< articles.length; i++) {
    if (articles[i] !== elem) {
        articles[i].classList.remove('active');
    } else {
        articles[i].classList.toggle('active');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var output = document.querySelectorAll('.output');

function hideAll(){
  //Function to hide all active divs
  var allActive = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
  allActive.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove('active')
  })
}

output.forEach(function(item) {
  //Adding click listener on articles
  item.onclick = function(){
    var datas = this.dataset.tab;
    var elem = document.querySelector('.article-' + datas);
    if(elem.classList.contains('active')){
     //If already active remove
     elem.classList.remove('active')
    }
    else{
      //If not already active, before add active remove all
      hideAll()
      elem.classList.add('active')
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.article-1, .article-2, .article-3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
}

.article-1 {
  background: red;
}

.article-2 {
  background: green;
}

.article-3 {
  background: blue;
}

.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="output" data-tab="1">BUTTON 1</h2>
<h2 class="output" data-tab="2">BUTTON 2</h2>
<h2 class="output" data-tab="3">BUTTON 3</h2>


<div class=" article-1"></div>
<div class=" article-2"></div>
<div class=" article-3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution: Just remove the class for all elements, then add like you did.

```
var output = document.querySelectorAll('.output');

output.forEach(function(item)
{

 item.onclick = function()
 {

   var datas = this.dataset.tab;

   // ----------------  so just add this bit..
   var alltabs=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
   for(var i=0;i<alltabs.length;i++)
   {
    alltabs[i].classList.remove('active');
   }
   // ---------------- and then go on like you did.. (only don't toggle, just add)

   var elem = document.querySelector('.article-' + datas);
   elem.classList.add('active');

 }
});
```